# submit button not working in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

In my django template when I render whole form at once, submit button works and forms get submitted or error shows up if there's any:

```
<form action="" method="POST" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 large-8 columns">
                            {{ form }}
                            <input type="submit" value="submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
```

but when I render like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-6 columns">
                            {{ form.name }}
                            <input type="submit" value="submit">
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-6 columns">
                            {{ form.email}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-6 columns">
                            {{ form.model_no}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-6 columns">
                            {{ form.phone_no}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 columns">
                            {{ form.problem_details}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

on submitting, page just reloads and nothing happens neither form submits nor errors shows up.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'query_form.views.contactview', name="home"),
        url(r'^thankyou/', 'query_form.views.thankyou', name="thankyou"),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

views.py: http://pastebin.com/TGzkh7aq

I want to use second method for proper styling. Please help.

I've got answers that I should provide an 'action' to the form but my questions is why the first method working and second not without 'action'.

edit: on using `action="{% url 'thankyou' %}"` I'm getting following error:

`NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'thankyou' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

**update**: I was missing comma in urls.py, that's was causing the above error. I've updated the code.

But now my form is getting submitted because of `action` even when it is empty without showing any error. Just like a link to `thankyou` page.

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py` file? Ultimately, you're missing an `action` in your form, which handles the redirect after you submit, but knowing where you'd like the form to end up once you press the submit button will help me to form a more complete solution.

Comment: @vicodin Chances are that your data has errors but you can't see them. Look at my answer for the link to documentation.

Comment: try in urls.py   from query_form.views import thankyou and then url(r'^thankyou/$', thankyou, name="thankyou"),    if this generates an error on the import then your paths are wrong.

Comment: @mtnpaul after reading your comment I realised the mistake and have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a probability that you have not added a field on the form which is required hence making it unable to submit

Answer (score 1):

If you take total control of the HTML rendering then you should [output the errors by yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually):

```
{{ form.name.errors }}
```

Comment: And `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` at the top of the form as well.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sure. As shown at the very first line of the first example at the linked docs :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's solve the problem of error handling but still my form is not submitting.

Comment: @vicodin I had the same issue you are having but after surrounding the form opening {% block content %} and closing {% endblock content %} it worked.

Answer (score 1):

With this template, you will be able to use Twitter Bootstrap with your Django forms

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" {% if form.is_multipart %}enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.media }}
{% if form.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        <ul>
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="control-group {{ field.html_name }} {% if field.errors %}error{% endif %}">
        <label class="control-label">{{ field.label }}{% if field.field.required %} *{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {{ field }}
            {% if field.errors %}<span class="help-inline">{{ field.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}

{% block formsets %}
    {% for formset in inlines %}
        {% include "inline_formset.html" with formset=formset %}
    {% endfor %}        
{% endblock formsets %}

<div class="form-actions">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    {% block extra_buttons %}
    {% endblock extra_buttons %}
</div>
```

Comment: I can use that but I want to know why submit button not working in second case.

Answer (score 0):

First try including an action for your form.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **action="."** ? I think this will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, I came across the same problem, `type="submit"` inside a div seems to be the problem. You can solve it by using `input` tag with the same properties, as for the name you can use the `value` property of `input` tag. If you want to know why input tags work and div tags don't please check out the link below

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/][1]